# What can be some bachelor thesis ideas in quantum random walks?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, research, quantum-walks

**Note:** *Cross-posted on [Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/42714/what-can-be-some-bachelor-thesis-ideas-in-quantum-random-walks).*

---

I am an undergraduate, reading about quantum information and quantum technology. For about some time, I have been interested in the applications of quantum walks to quantum algorithms. What can be some bachelor thesis ideas in quantum random walks? Can anybody suggest a starting point?

Comment: What do you know about the Childs, Cleve, Deotto, Farhi, Gutman, and Spielman [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0209131) on welded trees?  [This question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21483/applications-of-quantum-walks?rq=1) also has some good suggestions.

Comment: @Mark S Thanks for your comment. I haven't yet read this paper. I'll check it out. And thanks for the suggestions link as well.

Comment: are you still looking for an answer? Where are you based? Have a look at Open Quantum Walks by Prof. F. Petruccione.

Comment: @Hazmatally Thanks for the comment. I am based in India. I'll have a look at your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, after a bit of deliberation, I'm afraid that I believe this is off-topic as a result of essentially being too broad c.f. [this post](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/802/43116) on tcs - feel free to ask about whether a specific topic is ok or if you have a good reason this should be on topic, please make a post on [meta]